# What can I do about my build error in Visual Studio 2019 .net core? cannot find part of path \obj\Debug\net48\Package\PackageTmp

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I am so confused, this is my error:

```
1>obj\Debug\net48\Package\PackageTmp.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3000,5): error : Copying file obj\Debug\net48\NuGet\DD3A9BE7C0EDA549CD5B7B690E0621F0E2C932EC\Glass.Mapper.Sc.100\5.8.173\App_Config/Include/Glass/Glass.Mapper.Sc.Start.config to obj\Debug\net48\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Debug\net48\NuGet\DD3A9BE7C0EDA549CD5B7B690E0621F0E2C932EC\Glass.Mapper.Sc.100\5.8.173\App_Config/Include/Glass/Glass.Mapper.Sc.Start.config failed. Could not find a part of the path 'obj\Debug\net48\Package\PackageTmp\obj\Debug\net48\NuGet\DD3A9BE7C0EDA549CD5B7B690E0621F0E2C932EC\Glass.Mapper.Sc.100\5.8.173\App_Config/Include/Glass/Glass.Mapper.Sc.Start.config'.
1>Done building project "some.project.ORM.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

I have tried to delete the obj\Debug folder in the file system as well as the solution, as some have suggested. I have unloaded the project to review the .csproj file, I didn't see anything strange. I tried removing the Nuget Package and Reinstalling it. I just am not certain.
any help would be welcomed.

Note: I checked the directories do exist and they do. I even deleted the /obj/Debug folders from the solution as well as the source, as suggested, nothing seems to be working.

here is the .csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>some.project.ORM</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>some.project.ORM</AssemblyName>
    <PublishTargetType>website</PublishTargetType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)\_Build\props\_PublishTargetType.props" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Glass.Mapper.Sc.100" Version="5.8.173" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="App_Config\Include\Foundation\Glass\Glass.Mapper.Sc.Start.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Can you share your `csproj` file? Did you double-check that all paths do exist?

Comment: @mu88 this issue was because the file that I was copying to was over the 260 limit in VS. My path length was 261. We copying the solution to a shorter path and the build worked fine. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this issue was because the file that I was copying to was over the 260 limit in VS. My path length was 261. We copied the solution to a shorter path and the build worked fine. thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider adding an answer and changing its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: @JingmiaoXu-MSFT glad to do this, how do I make this update

Comment: See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)